# kubectl exec output not getting stored in variable

Tags: bash, kubectl

I am trying to do a kubectl exec and store value into a variable. But the variable displays null. If i use -it in the exec, it works. Since while running with terraform says can't allocate terminal, I need to run it without -it.

Command I run: `abc=$(kubectl exec nginx-6799fc88d8-xpzs9 -- nginx -v)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify your command as following(`-it`):

```
abc=$(kubectl exec -it nginx-6799fc88d8-xpzs9 -- nginx -v)
```

The reason for this behavior is `nginx -v` is displaying the output over `stderr` not `stdout`.  This means, the command you were using would work for any other commands like `ls` , `cat` etc which display output over `stdout`.

**Alternate approach** by redirecting stderr to stdout(`2>&1`) :

```
abc=$(kubectl exec nginx-6799fc88d8-xpzs9 -- nginx -v 2>&1)
```

Example:

```
x=$(k exec nginx  -- nginx -v 2>&1)
echo "$x"
nginx version: nginx/1.21.3
```

Comment: so, in my case - using null resource in terraform where I cannot use ```-it ```. Is there an alternate option?

Comment: @karikevinod see update.

Answer (score 0):

As @P.... Mentioned alternative approach for replacing **-it** is using **2>&1**

- File descriptor **1** is the standard output (**stdout**).
- File descriptor **2** is the standard error (**stderr**).
- **-i** Pass stdin to the container(**stdin**)
- **-t** Stdin is a TTY(**tty**)

Here is one way to remember this construct: at first, 2>1 may look like a good way to redirect stderr to stdout. However, it will actually be interpreted as "redirect stderr to a file named 1". & indicates that what follows and precedes is a file descriptor and not a filename. So the construct becomes: 2>&1.

Consider **>&** as a redirect merger operator.

For more details, refer this [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#exec) on kubectl exec command.